# Insert text into Markitup text editor

Tags: jquery, markitup

I've wrote a code

```
$(".ka_opinions_quote a").click(function(){
    var quoted_text = $(this).parents("div.o_opinion").find(".ka_opinion_txt").text();
    var cite_uri = $(this).parents("div.o_opinion").prev().find("a").attr("href");
    var curr_text = $(".editor").text();

    $(".editor").text(curr_text+'<quote cite="<?php echo mb_substr(JURI::base(), 0, -1); ?>'+cite_uri+'">'+quoted_text+'</quote>');
});
```

After click text insert in textarea. But if user insert or write some text into textarea or delete text and after click on quote link, text not displaying in textarea but in Firebug I've see but actually text already exists

[image]

Any ideas how I do implement a proper text insertion?

Answer (score 1):

I've modified example, which comes with markitup (take a look over *index.html* in the Markitup! archive) and here what we've got:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="markitup/jquery.markitup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="markitup/sets/default/set.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="markitup/skins/markitup/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="markitup/sets/default/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('#markItUp').markItUp(mySettings);
    $('.add').click(function() {
        $.markItUp( {   openWith:'<opening tag>',
                        closeWith:'<\/closing tag>',
                        placeHolder:document.getSelection()
                    }
                );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<p>Click <a href="#" class="add">this link to insert content</a> from anywhere in the page</p>
<p>
<textarea id="markItUp" cols="80" rows="20">
&lt;h1&gt;Welcome on markItUp!&lt;/h1&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;markItUp!&lt;/strong&gt; is a JavaScript plugin built on the jQuery library. It allows you to turn any textarea into a markup editor. Html, Textile, Wiki Syntax, Markdown, BBcode or even your own markup system can be easily implemented.&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You set cursor position in the textarea, select text and click link "...add content...". Script simply puts text you've selected into textarea in the cursor position. Sorry for using *document.getSelection()* - haven't found any similar utility function in jQuery =)

Comment: Thanks! I've added "target" parameter in $.markItUp({}); for automatically text inserting if textarea isn't focused.

Answer (score 0):

it  depends on which editor you use.
for markItUp you can theese;

```
$.markItUp({ name:"YourWord", openWith:"[b]", closeWith:"[/b]" })
$.markItUp({ replaceWith: "yourCustomEntry" });
```